# dijit Tree : finding treenode associated with new data store item

Tags: tree, dojo

I want to highlight a programmatically inserted node.  I'm inserting using store.newItem; this gives me a datastore item.  To do the highlighting, I need a treenode.  Can someone tell me how to find the treenode associated with the item?

Thanks,
Larry

Answer (score 0):

Tree.getNodesByItem()

It returns an array since there may be multiple TreeNodes for a given item, although usually there's just one.